# What does "make oneself heard above the chatter" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

Example sentences:

> Many people are glad to have someone who can make themselves heard above the chatter.
>
> How can you make yourself heard above the chatter?

I know the meaning of every single word in this phrase but do not get the meaning readily. What does *make oneself heard above the chatter* mean?

Comment: _Make yourself heard_ = speak loudly and clearly enough for people to hear what you are saying.

Comment: The 'chatter' is the sound of other nearby conversations.